# KryoNet RMI Code works on PC but not on Android

Tags: java, android, networking, kryonet

I've written some code to utilize the RMI feature of KryoNet. I've followed the examples and it all worked great on my computer.

However when running the same code from within an Android application I get "com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.TimeoutException". Here's the full stacktrace:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.TimeoutException: Response timed out: xyz.test.lib.capabilities.IServerControl.getServerUptime
at     com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(ObjectSpace.java:408)
 at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
 at $Proxy0.getServerUptime(Unknown Source)
 at xyz.test.clientandroid.testClient.init(TestClient.java:70)
 at xyz.test.clientandroid.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:36)
```

What might be causing this?

I've changed the log level to STRACE and the conversation with the server looks as if everything worked out:

```
DEBUG: [kryonet] Connection 2 sent TCP: PacketLogin (26)
TRACE: [kryonet] Connection listener added: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$RemoteInvocationHandler$1
TRACE: [kryonet] Client listener added.
TRACE: [kryo] Write class 15: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethod
DEBUG: [kryo] Write: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethod
TRACE: [kryo] Object graph complete.
TRACE: [kryo] Read class 16: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult
TRACE: [kryo] Read field: objectID (com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult)
TRACE: [kryo] Read: 2
TRACE: [kryo] Read field: responseID (com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult)
TRACE: [kryo] Read: -63
TRACE: [kryo] Read field: result (com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult)
TRACE: [kryo] Read class 7: long
TRACE: [kryo] Read: 182710
DEBUG: [kryo] Read: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult
TRACE: [kryo] Object graph complete.
TRACE: [kryonet] Connection 2 sent TCP: InvokeMethod (9)
TRACE: [kryonet] Connection 2 received TCP: InvokeMethodResult
DEBUG: [kryonet] Connection 2 sent: IServerControl#getServerUptime() (9)
TRACE: [kryo] Read class 16: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult
TRACE: [kryo] Read field: objectID (com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult)
TRACE: [kryo] Read: 2
TRACE: [kryo] Read field: responseID (com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult)
TRACE: [kryo] Read: -63
TRACE: [kryo] Read field: result (com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult)
TRACE: [kryo] Read class 7: long
TRACE: [kryo] Read: 182710
DEBUG: [kryo] Read: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.rmi.ObjectSpace$InvokeMethodResult
TRACE: [kryo] Object graph complete.
TRACE: [kryonet] Connection 2 received TCP: InvokeMethodResult
```

I didn't think it was necessary to attach any code as that doesn't seem to be the problem. If anyone would like to see it I will gladly post it, though.

The Android SDK which I've been using is version 23.

Thank you

Comment: Well the exception is definitely thrown [here](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/kryonet/rmi/ObjectSpace.java#L447-492) but I don't know why.

Comment: Are you by chance using **UDP**? Or are you using **TCP**?

Comment: The network traffic is TCP.

Comment: Hrmm..  If it had been UDP the answer would have been obvious, but if it's TCP,  then I don't know what could be wrong...